# Como tomar la variable de un select en PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, bootstrap

Disculpen. Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy desarrollando un sistema de aula virtual y estoy desde el módulo de profesor, con una clase de aula creada, ahora necesito agregar estudiantes y lo hago desde una tabla por medio de un `select` con la opción ***"Agregar"***. Resulta que no me está tomando la variable del `select`, y por ello no me está agregando ningún estudiante a la clase del profesor.

```
   <?php include('header_dashboard.php'); ?>
    <?php include('session.php'); ?>
    <?php $get_id = $_GET['id']; ?>
        <body>
            <?php include('navbar_teacher.php'); ?>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <?php include('class_sidebar.php'); ?>
                    <div class="span9" id="content">
                         <div class="row-fluid">
                             <!-- breadcrumb -->
                             <div class="pull-right">
                                 <a href="my_students.php<?php echo '?id='.$get_id; ?>" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i> Regresar</a>
                             </div>
                             <?php $class_query = mysql_query("SELECT * from teacher_class
                                        LEFT JOIN class ON class.class_id = teacher_class.class_id
                                        LEFT JOIN subject ON subject.subject_id = teacher_class.subject_id
                                        where teacher_class_id = '$get_id'")or die(mysql_error());
                                        $class_row = mysql_fetch_array($class_query);
                                ?>

                                <ul class="breadcrumb">
                                   <li><a href="#"><?php echo $class_row['class_name']; ?></a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
                                   <li><a href="#"><?php echo $class_row['subject_code']; ?></a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
                                   <li><a href="#">Mis Estudiantes</a><span class="divider">/</span></li>
                                   <li><a href="#"><b>Agregar Estudiante</b></a></li>
                                 </ul>

                         <!-- end breadcrumb -->

                        <!-- block -->
                        <div id="block_bg" class="block">
                            <div class="navbar navbar-inner block-header">
                                <div id="" class="muted pull-left"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="block-content collapse in">
                            <div class="span12">
                                <form method="post" action="">
                                    <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-save"></i>&nbsp;Agregar Estudiante</button>
                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table" id="example">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Foto</th>
                                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                                <th>Año de Curso y Sección</th>
                                                <th></th>
                                            </tr>
                                         </thead>
                                         <tbody>

                                             <?php

                                                 print_r($_POST);
                                                 $a = 0 ;
                                                 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * from student LEFT JOIN class on class.class_id = student.class_id") or die(mysql_error());
                                                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                                                $id = $row['student_id'];
                                                $a++;

                                              ?>

                                             <tr>
                                                 <input type="hidden" name="test" value="<?php echo $a; ?>">
                                                 <td width="70"><img  class="img-rounded" src="admin/<?php echo $row['location']; ?>" height="50" width="40"></td>
                                                 <td><?php echo $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname']; ?></td> 
                                                 <td><?php echo $row['class_name']; ?></td> 

                                                  <td width="80">
                                                      <select name="add_student<?php echo $a; ?>" class="span12">
                                                          <option></option>
                                                          <option value="add_student">Agregar</option>
                                                       </select>

                                                       <input type="hidden" name="student_id<?php echo $a; ?>" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                                                       <input type="hidden" name="class_id<?php echo $a; ?>" value="<?php echo $get_id; ?>">
                                                       <input type="hidden" name="teacher_id<?php echo $a; ?>" value="<?php echo $session_id; ?>">

                                                  </td>

                                                  <?php } ?>    

                                             </tr>
                                         </tbody>
                                     </table>
                                 </form>
                                 <?php

                                     if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

                                          $test = $_POST['test'];
                                          for($b = 1; $b <=  $test; $b++)
                                     {




                                      $test1 = "student_id".$b;
                                      $test2 = "class_id".$b;
                                      $test3 = "teacher_id".$b;
                                      $test4 = "add_student".$b;

                                      $id = $_POST[$test1];
                                      $class_id = $_POST[$test2];
                                      $teacher_id = $_POST[$test3];
                                      $Add = $_POST[$test4];

                                      $query = mysql_query("SELECT * from teacher_class_student where student_id = '$id' and teacher_class_id = '$class_id' ")or die(mysql_error());
                                      $count = mysql_num_rows($query); 

                                      if ($count > 0){ ?>
                                          <script>
                                               alert('El estudiante ya se encuentra en la clase'); 
                                          </script>
                                          <script>
                                               window.location = "add_student.php<?php echo '?id='.$get_id; ?>"; 
                                           </script>

                                   <?php
                                       }else if($Add == 'Add'){
                                            mysql_query("INSERT into teacher_class_student (teacher_class_id,student_id,teacher_id) values('$class_id','$id','$teacher_id') ")or die(mysql_error());


                                        } else{



                                        }



                                    ?>
                                    <script>
                                        window.location = "my_students.php<?php echo '?id='.$get_id; ?>"; 
                                    </script>

                                   <?php
                                       }



                                       }



                                    ?>
                                  <?php ?>
                              </tbody>
                           </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /block -->
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  <?php include('footer.php'); ?>
  </div>
        <?php include('script.php'); ?>
</body>

  array (size=43)
  'submit' => string '' (length=0)
  'example_length' => string '10' (length=2)
  'test' => string '10' (length=2)
  'add_student1' => string '' (length=0)
  'student_id1' => string '222' (length=3)
  'class_id1' => string '209' (length=3)
  'teacher_id1' => string '13' (length=2)
  'add_student2' => string '' (length=0)
  'student_id2' => string '221' (length=3)
  'class_id2' => string '209' (length=3)
  'teacher_id2' => string '13' (length=2)
  'add_student3' => string '' (length=0)
  'student_id3' => string '223' (length=3)
  'class_id3' => string '209' (length=3)
  'teacher_id3' => string '13' (length=2)
  'add_student4' => string '' (length=0)
  'student_id4' => string '224' (length=3)
  'class_id4' => string '209' (length=3)
  'teacher_id4' => string '13' (length=2)
  'add_student5' => string '' (length=0)
  'student_id5' => string '113' (length=3)
  'class_id5' => string '209' (length=3)
  'teacher_id5' => string '13' (length=2)
  'add_student6' => string '' (length=0)
  'student_id6' => string '112' (length=3)
  'class_id6' => string '209' (length=3)
  'teacher_id6' => string '13' (length=2)
  'add_student7' => string '' (length=0)
  'student_id7' => string '111' (length=3)
  'class_id7' => string '209' (length=3)
  'teacher_id7' => string '13' (length=2)
  'add_student8' => string '' (length=0)
  'student_id8' => string '108' (length=3)
  'class_id8' => string '209' (length=3)
  'teacher_id8' => string '13' (length=2)
  'add_student9' => string '' (length=0)
  'student_id9' => string '105' (length=3)
  'class_id9' => string '209' (length=3)
  'teacher_id9' => string '13' (length=2)
  'add_student10' => string '' (length=0)
  'student_id10' => string '106' (length=3)
  'class_id10' => string '209' (length=3)
  'teacher_id10' => string '13' (length=2)
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla. También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: ¿Puedes hacer un `var_dump($_POST);` en PHP para ver qué es lo que te está llegando realmente?

Comment: array (size=43)
  'submit' => string '' (length=0)
  'example_length' => string '10' (length=2)
  'test' => string '10' (length=2)
  'add_student1' => string '' (length=0)
  'student_id1' => string '222' (length=3)
  'class_id1' => string '211' (length=3)
  'teacher_id1' => string '22' (length=2)
  'add_student2' => string '' (length=0)
  'student_id2' => string '221' (length=3)
  'class_id2' => string '211' (length=3)
  'teacher_id2' => string '22' (length=2)
  'add_student3' => string 'add_student' (length=11)
@A.Cedano
  No me toma el select

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el dump. En comentaris es difícil de leer...

Comment: Que va, aun nada, igualmente gracias por la sugerencia, se mantiene igual. Sucede algo, ingrese 2 alumnos manualmente en la tabla del aula y me los refleja claramente en el sistema pero, al agregar otro estudiante, si selecciono estudiantes o no lo hago igualmente me dice que los estudiantes ya estan en la clase incluso si no son los que ya pertenecen a la misma, Solo con darle al boton agregar sin seleccionar alguno ya me arroja el alert "El estudiante ya se encuentra en la clase".

Comment: La cosa está algo confusa y el código no ayuda demasiado por la forma en que lo tienes estructurado. Nos centraremos en la parte del `INSERT` que es la que dices que no funciona. ¿Qué depuraste en esa parte? Deberías comprobar dos cosas: 1º. Que el código está llegando a ese bloque, poniendo un simple `echo "Cualquier cosa";` 2º. Debes verificar las variables que creas ahí, concatenando otro tipo de información que traes de la base de datos. Me refiero a las variables como esta: `$test1 = "student_id".$b;` y a todas las otras: `$test2, $test3...`  debes hacer `echo`de ellas a ver que tienen.

Comment: Pon también el `INSERT` es una variable y sácalo por pantalla: `$sqlInsert="INSERT into teacher_class_student (teacher_class_id,student_id,teacher_id) values('$class_id','$id','$teacher_id') ";  y luego: `echo $sqlInsert;`  Acostumbra siempre cuando algo no funcione a mostrar las cosas, a ver qué estás creando, no asumas que un código va a funcionar o tomar variables porque sí. ¿Una consulta no funciona? 1º. Imprime esa consulta, revisa que está bien; 2º. Copia esa consulta y trata de ejecutarla directamente en la base de datos. O sea, tienes que aprender técnicas de depuración.

Comment: Buenas esto es lo que me arroja del insert. Y si, debo aprender tecnicas de depuracion, la verdad estoy aprendiendo a programar.

Resource id #17 Resource id #18 Resource id #19INSERT into teacher_class_student (teacher_class_id,student_id,teacher_id) values('211','223','22') Resource id #20INSERT into teacher_class_student (teacher_class_id,student_id,teacher_id) values('211','224','22') Resource id #21 Resource id #22 Resource id #23 Resource id #24 Resource id #25 Resource id #26

Answer (score 0):

Si te fijas bien el valor que obtienes en el `<select name="add_student<?php echo $a; ?>" class="span12">` es add_student cuando el mismo es seleccionado. Por lo menos es lo que dice en el option `<option value="add_student">Agregar</option>` .

Pero para realizar el insert estas preguntando si el $bAdd == 'Add', por ende nunca se va a dar esa condición. Si cambias esta condición podría funcionar:

```
if ($count > 0){ ?>
    <script>
        alert('El estudiante ya se encuentra en la clase');
    </script>
    <script>
        window.location = "add_student.php<?php echo '?id='.$get_id; ?>";
    </script>

<?php
}else if($Add == 'add_student'){
    mysql_query("INSERT into teacher_class_student (teacher_class_id,student_id,teacher_id) values('$class_id','$id','$teacher_id') ")or die(mysql_error());


} else{



}
```

Por el momento no veo otro problema. Espero te sea útil.